# Keep Camera relative to left half of a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to place my camera on the x-axis relative to a gameobject (in my case a sphere). I need this to preview only the half of that sphere no matter what resolution the window will be.
So if the user resizes the window, the camera should adjust itself to only see the left half. See the attached Image. Red is the cameras view and black is the Sphere

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything to get this to work? Are you using an orthographic camera or perspective camera?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know how to start, so I haven't tried anything. It is a perspective camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Camera.ViewerportPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportPointToRay.html) function you can get a position and direction in world space from a point on the screen. Screen coordinates are defined as (0,0) on the bottom left to (1, 1) on the top right. So to position the sphere on the middle right of the screen you'll want to convert the screen coordinate (1, 0.5) to world coordinates.

Here's an idea of how to get the point on the middle-right of the screen half-way between the near and far clip planes of the camera:

```
// get the world ray from screen coordinates
Ray ray = camera.ViewpoirtPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 0.5, 0));

// make the z-component of the direction 1
ray.direction /= ray.direction.z;

// get the world position for where to place the sphere by scaling the ray
// halfway down the camera's frustum
Vector3 worldPos = ray.origin + ray.direction * (camera.far - camera.near) * 0.5;
sphere.position = worldPos;
```

Hopefully that helps! Let me know if anything is unclear!